# File is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I am developing a c# application, backend as sqlite.In my application i have an option for clean databse.It means the curren .db file will delete using File.Delete method and again it create empty databse using File.create method.Now let me explain the problem.

To perform cleandatabse task, i have to stop all the process which is running ,after doing that if i click on clean database it is throwing an error that file cannot delete, it is being used by another process.i am able to stop all the thread which is running.

Somehow i am able to find which process is blocikng the file ,

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses()) {
                var files = GetFilesLockedBy(process);
                if (files.Contains(filePath))
                {
                    procs.Add(process);
                    Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
                    process.Kill();
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                }
            }
```

But in the above code i used process.Kill, which close the window form which i am running.
without using kill, i tried close and dispose which doesn't work for me.

Can you please help me to release the file from the process without closing the application and then yo delete the db file.

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Sangita.

Comment: @user703526 - Why do not simple delete the contents of the database instead of the database file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure you close every stream you open it:

```
using (Stream str = File.Create("C:\\h.txt"))
{
// your code here
} // the stream will be automatically closed here
```

if you don't put this `using` statement, it will cause you a lot of bugs, even if you close it manually `str.Close();`

Answer (score 3):

`Streams`s are disposable types, you must manage their lifetime manually, either by that `using` syntax, e.g.:

```
using (StreamReader f = new ...) {
}
```

... or by doing it more verbosely (this syntax is required if you allocate and delete the `Stream` in different code-blocks/functions):

```
try {
    StreamReader f = new ...;
    ...
} finally {
    if (null != f) f.Dispose();
}
```

... or by making the holding class an `IDisposable` by itself. See also [What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/idisposable.aspx).

---

Interestingly, this seems to be a practical incarnation of one of those https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths/2245382#2245382 :

> **0) In C++, you must mess around with pointers, that's old and dangerous, use C#**
>
> Gee, #include `boost/shared_ptr>` or one of the like. Actually, it is often easier to produce mess in your sowonderful C#:

```
static void Main () {
    foo();
    bar();
}
static void foo () {
    var f = new StreamWriter ("hello.txt");
    f.Write ("hello world");
}
static void bar () {
    var f = new StreamReader ("hello.txt");
    Console.WriteLine (f.ReadToEnd ());
}
```

> > "Unhandled IOException: The process cannot access the file 'hello.txt' because it is being used by another process."
>
> Those claims, btw, are often made by those who happen to never have heard of RAII, and about how far you can get without even smart-pointers.

Comment: File class is static. You can't new it, you can't dispose it. Edit the first part of your answer and replace File with Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you may be calling Kill on the current process.
EDIT : call Delte after the loop.
Try this :

```
int currentProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses()) {
              if (process.Id != currentProcessId)
              {
                var files = GetFilesLockedBy(process);
                if (files.Contains(filePath))
                {
                    procs.Add(process);
                    Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName);
                    process.Kill();
                }
              }
            }
File.Delete(filePath);
```

Moreover Close doesn't terminate the process, you have to call CloseMainWindow or Kill.

Comment: My problem is process.kill() method, i dont want to kill the process which is my application.Is ther any way to release the file which is being used.

Comment: Sure, close any stream opened on this file.

Comment: This file is opened as a connection string, i mean the path of the database file is the connection string.Also i  am closing all the connections.

Comment: The following line is used in my code.            string executingDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");
Will it create any problem to delete.